# Load testing with Jmeter on EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-ec2, jmeter, load-testing

I'm a manual tester, now I learned Jmeter at the beginner level. I'm trying to load test with a post API on the AWS server. Jmeter is running good & showing the result that I needed. But the problem I faced that the test result is not reflecting on the EC2 server.

So how do I reflect the test result of the Jmeter to the Amazon server?
It would be very helpful if anyone guides me.

Comment: What you mean by test result not reflecting on the EC2 server. Please give more details.

Comment: I meant suppose I getting proper result i.e. if I run 500 or 1000 threads in 1 second the result is showing failure percentage is greater than success from Jmeter but in the server end not receiving any deflection of it.

Comment: So you mean, You are using Jmeter to push 1000 threads in 1 second and getting huge number of failures in Jmeter aggregate results screen. But, your application logs not showing any failures. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  
Thanks for your valuable comments but I solved it already. Actually, any good server will not allow me hitting 1000 threads within 1 second. It will block the IP for a certain time during testing. But if I use 500 threads within 30 seconds it's reflecting on the server end.

Comment: @RaktimBanerjee suppose 1000 users may visit at the same time when there is some offer in the websites than how will you test that scenario

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the impact of your test (i.e. how CPU/RAM consumption increases, how network interfaces and disks are behaving, etc.) the easiest solution would be enabling [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) on the EC2 server under test. This way you will be able to collect the metrics and see [graphs and statistics](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/details/#graphs-and-statistics) without having to install and configure any extra software.

---

If for any reason Amazon CloudWatch is not acceptable another option will be using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/), you will need to install PerfMon Metrics Collector listener plugin for JMeter and run [ServerAgent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) on the EC2 server (don't forget to open the relevant port - `4444` by default in [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html) and your operating system firewall) for both TCP and UDP protocols.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for more information and comprehensive installation and configuration instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but I solved it already. Actually, any good server will not allow me hitting 1000 threads within 1 second. It will block the IP for a certain time during testing. But if I use 500 threads within 30 seconds it's reflecting on the server end.